# Transpose is just the way of generalizing a dot product?

Tags: regression, correlation, geometry

It seems like $a^Tb$ is the same as writing $a \cdot b$ in matrix form.

1) Why is $n \times 1$ and $n \times 1$ matrix multiplication undefined?

2) Is this just a generalization of the dot product?

If so, is it just a way to generalization the orthogonal projection of one vector onto another, as a way to find the closest point on the second vector to the first vector? Does:

$$\frac{a\cdot b}{a\cdot a} = \frac{a^Tb}{a^Ta}$$?

And then, that quantity should equal p, which if I'm not mistaken equals yhat?

Comment: also, I think I'm going wrong in trying to deduce partial correlation from vectors. if we have x y z and all three are correlated, can I get the correlation between x and z by the dot product of (x-y*x)(z-y*z) where the asterisks represent the correlations/portions of the vector explained by y?

Comment: What is $\hat{y}$? What is $p$?

Comment: If $a$ and $b$ are column $n$-vectors, then, yes, $a^tb$ equals $a\cdot b$.